# Laravel SQL relation

Tags: sql, laravel, relation

My Tabels look like this

[image]

I have several devices. For example device1, device2, device3 etc.
Each device goes to a Kit. Each active Kit has the attribute active = 1

For Example i have device1 and device2 first in Kit1. Then device1 and device2 goes to Kit 2. I set Kit1 to active = 0 and Kit2 has active = 1. Then I "remove" device1 and device2 From Kit2. (It will still be in devicekit). I only set Kit2 to active = 0.

And here is my problem. I want to list all devices, where are not in a Kit. So if I do a left join to Devicekit and Kit, i want to check, if all Kits are active = 0.

I tried something like `SUM(kit.active) as activesum` and if `activesum` is 0, the device is in no kit anymore. But this does not work.

Comment: why are you not using the model relationships

Comment: I tried, but i don't know how exactly to do. Also i tried this SQL: `SELECT d.*, SUM(k.active) as sumactive FROM devices AS d LEFT JOIN devicekits AS dk ON dk.id_device = d.id LEFT JOIN kits as k ON k.id = dk.id_kit WHERE sumactive = 0 GROUP BY d.id;` But i get an Error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'sumactive' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe you're after something like this:

```
select * from device d
where id not in (select id_device 
                 from devicekit dk
                 join kit k on dk.id_kit = k.id 
                 where k.active = 1)
```

This will list devices that are not in any active kit. You can play around with an example created [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28abda2b1204ec459182441a1bbf02aa).